# Starting a Thin application via cron

Tags: ruby, dashboard, thin

I am running Shopify Dashboard on Centos 6 (http://shopify.github.io/dashing/). I wish to start this on boot and via a cron when I pull down an update from git.

I have the following code in a bash script which is the same code I run via the command line to start dashboard.

`#!/bin/bash`

`cd /usr/share/dashboard/`

`dashing start -p 500 -d`

running the actual script as the root user from the command line starts the application no problem.

However when this script is run via a cron or on boot then the application is never started.

If anyone could shed some light as to why this is the case it would most appreciated.

Comment: What user is the cron job run from?  By your description it would have to be root.

Comment: Yes the cron job is running as the root user.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment I am still not 100% sure that the script is being run as root.  I would add a line in the script:

```
echo $user > /tmp/test.txt
```

Then run the script via cron and see what the value of the file is.

Also I question your script.  Why is it necessary to cd?

How about

```
/usr/share/dashboard/dashing start -p 500 -d
```

Also you may have to do a nohup, which is the no hang up signal, so ...

```
nohup /usr/share/dashboard/dashing start -p 500 -d
```

Those are my guesses.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. I added the top line and outputted the user to the text file. the resultant was a blank file, which does suggest that the user is not being specified. However I am specifying the user in the crontab.

Comment: I have the same problem, still trying to find the reason. As for @Pete B.'s questions, dashing is perhaps not a standard command and expects to be run from within the folder where the dashboard project was created. It looks like cron has some particular way to run the commands instead of the same behaviour the command line will produce.

Comment: ps: the last argument "-d" also sends the process to background without need to use the "nohup" command.